# My Site goes to Maintenance spontaneously

Tags: maintenance-mode

My site goes to maintenance mode **spontaneously** almost every day.
I am advised by users.

Everything works fine when I put it out of maintenance mode.

Any explanation is welcome

(Drupal 7.59)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error came from the Backup & Migrate Module : I had an error when I wanted to access the "Schedule" folder.

When I unstalled the Module, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

This can have a lot of reasons but I try to help to investigate:

1. Be sure only you can have the permission to put the site into maintenance mode
2. You should search for the "state" variable name of the maintenance mode, if am not mistaken it's called `maintenance_mode`. Based on the results you should have a clear view which code parts may change it's state.

Comment: @Jacques-Marie Also, make sure that you're the only one who have the permission to put the site in maintenance mode i.e. are there other admins on the site?

Comment: I am the only full admin

Answer (score 0):

If you're having both live and staging instances, and using caching (memcache for example) check your caching configuration.

If your staging configuration is (by error) set to the same key it may be interfering with the live site, where the live site is reading the configuration from cached staging data, or something of the sorts...

Comment: Actually, I also have a (subdomain) dev site ... which also goes to maintenance spontaneously (I just realized).